# Rails helper for encode input value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, input, helper

Is it possible, to encrypt input value to some encrypting as here:

http://dzone.com/snippets/quick-two-encryption

But do this in view, so that view has not to much logic, maybe do as helper? But how?

for example change such string

```
<input name="person" value="1" />
```

to

```
<input name="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b" value="1" />
```

So, how to encode input name in rails?

Also please do not ask me why i need to do this... Have answer? Give it...

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate helper, and put there

```
module EncryptorHelper
    def encrypt_string(name)
    secret = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(name)
        a = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret)
        b = a.encrypt("parts")
        b
  end
end
```

then you can just call ecnrypt_string(123) in your's input

Comment: In Rails 4 you should call encrypt_and_sign instead of encrypt and decrypt_and_verify instead of decrypt.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html

Comment: I know, I just wanted to add it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Neat idea.  This isn't tested at all, but you'll get the idea.  Couldn't you use method_missing to pass one of your encrypted strings in to figure out the real method name?  Have that handle the getter and setter.  Something like...

form.html.haml

```
# You'll need to create an encrypt helper.
form_for @model do |f|
  f.input encrypt(person)
```

model.rb

```
class Model

  def method_missing sym, *args
    secret = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("yourpass")
    a = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret)

    if sym =~ /^(\w+)=$/
      instance_variable_set "@#{a.decrypt($1)}", args[0]
    else
      instance_variable_get "@#{a.decrypt(sym)}"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: also note: i have input_tag in form_tag, but not form_for